# Difference between "Kind"and "Jugend"

Tags: usage

I am interested in not only the literal but the figurative differences between "Kind" and "Jugend"

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 2):

Kind: child

Kindheit: childhood

Jugend: youth

Comment: Correct, but "youth" can refer both to a person's age (="Jugend") and to a young person (="Jugendlicher"). It is relevant to point out that "Jugend" ONLY refers to the age. It does NOT mean "young person", the way "youth" does.